# Gnome icons disappeared and right click menus changing

Tags: gnome3

I am running into a weird problem. I installed gnome shell 3.18  on a mint install. It works and looks great but it tends to keep switching two different right click menus randomly. I have to toggle show icons on desktop to go from the second menu to the first menu.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `nautilus-desktop` process is crashing somehow. You should be able to restore normality by running the following command

```
nautilus-desktop &
```

For convenience you  may want to add a custom keyboard shortcut for this command.

Comment: Or figure out why it's crashing in the first place.